# Some photos fail to synchronize with my iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization

I have a large collection of photographs and I want to synchronize a selection of albums, totally around 2500 photos, ranging in file size from 400KB to 7MB, with most of them around 5MB-6MB. Only about 1300 synchronize.

I have unselected photo syncing in iTunes and synced, then wiped the iPod Cache folder from my desktop's disk and tried again, but the problem remains. I suspect file size, but the chap at the Apple store didn't think that was a problem. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: are you sure there is enough room for them all? My 8Gb CF card for camera will take around 400 photos at 7-9MB. if you have a 16GB iPad you will not have enough room for all those photos

Comment: They are 10.5GB, over 2776 files, so I guess they average just under 4 MB. It's a 32GB iPad, and there's plenty of room.